# WooCommerce: Thumbnails on Shop page displayed in 300 x 300 pixels no matter the settings

Tags: woocommerce

WooCommerce > Settings > Products > Display > Catalog Images is set as 500 x 500 (hard crop selected), and just in case, Settings > Media > Medium size is also set as 500 x 500.

Yet all product images on my Shop page are 300 x 300 pixels. It's not a CSS problem, I'm talking about the actual size of the images (right click on the image with Firefox > view image). I regenerated my thumbnails after each change of settings. The apparent size of the images is correct because the CSS makes them the right size, it's just that they are pixelated because they are served at the wrong size.

There's clearly a problem here. Any suggestion?

Comment: It depends on what image size your theme is using. `the_post_thumbnail( 'some-size' );`

Comment: Your comment helped me identify the source of the issue:  the parent theme was forcing the 300x300 size. Thanks!

Comment: Cool. Can you post an answer explaining what you did? That way you can accept that as the answer and get this question out of the "unanswered" pile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. Problem came from parent theme "Rebound" whose function `tw_woocommerce_thumb()` enforced a 300px product thumbnail width.